# Storing certain XML children in SQL

Tags: php, xml

We have a network connected thermometer on our network that outputs an XML stream when you connect to its web address (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/netfeellife.xml):

```
<request>
    <rf_status>0</rf_status>
    <getvalue>0</getvalue>
    <scan_time>Fri May 11 09:10:54 2018</scan_time>
    <itemnum>3</itemnum>
    <temperature>28.4</temperature>
    <humidity>41</humidity>
    <dection>0</dection>
    <water>0</water>
    <gas>0</gas>
    <smoke>0</smoke>
    <dw1>0</dw1>
    <dw2>0</dw2>
    <dw3>0</dw3>
    <dw4>0</dw4>
    <dw5>0</dw5>
    <dw6>0</dw6>
    <dw7>0</dw7>
    <dw8>0</dw8>
    <dw9>0</dw9>
</request>
```

However, as we haven't connected the water/gas/smoke detectors, those parts of the output will always be '0', so it doesn't make sense to store them, only the `<scan_time>`, `<temperature>` and `<humidity>`, which have numbers.
We also can't adjust the formatting of the XML, as it what the box creates.

My original code was like this:

```
 <?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/netfeellife.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=temperature;charset=utf8', 
    'root', 'password');
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
     $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO thermometer (`scan_time`, `itemnum`, 
     `temperature`, `humidity`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

     $limit = new LimitIterator(new IteratorIterator($xml), 2, 4);

     foreach ($limit as $row)
     {

      $scan_time = (string)$row;
      //$limit->next();
      $itemnum = (string)$row;
      //$limit->next();
      $temperature = (string)$row;
      //$limit->next();
      $humidity = (string)
      $limit->current();

      $stmt->execute(array($scan_time, $itemnum, $temperature, $humidity));
     }

    ?>
```

But that saved the data like this:

*scan_time                itemnum   temperature humidity*

41                          41        41          41

29.7                        30        30          30

3                            3         3           3

Fri May 11 19:53:15 2018     0         0           0

I've also tried adapting code from other queries on here - [Parse xml-file and insert into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808535/parse-xml-file-and-insert-into-mysql-database) - without much success.

How could I just extract the three elements I'd want and store them?
Thanks

Comment: Are we still using the security risky mysql_* functions, deprecated in [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) since 2013 and entirely removed in [PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) in 2015? Before anything fix this to current DB-APIs: mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thanks. My original PDO code wasn't working, which is why I thought I'd try using code from Stack Overflow to see if that would work (albeit an example that was posted back in 2012, before the functions were depreciated).

Answer (score 0):

As your document only includes one set of readings, then the `foreach()` is not needed, in fact it's causing the problem...

```
//foreach ($xml as $syn)
// {
$scan_time = $syn->scan_time;
$temperature = $syn->temperature;
$humidity = $syn->humidity;

$sql="INSERT INTO thermometer (scan_time, temperature, humidity) VALUES ('$scan_time','$temperature','$humidity')";
$query  = mysql_query($sql);

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
else
 {
     echo "Records added";
 }
 //}
```

(I've shown the lines to comment out).