# Map column name to field name LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, xml, postgresql, local, load-data-infile

I have just exported a data table in XML format from phpPgAdmin. I want to load this file into my local mysql database. The table structure is the same for both databases.

I know that mysql allows import of xml data using the example xml structure below:

```
<row>
<field name='column1'>value1</field>
```

My problem is that phpPgAdmin has exported the data in this format:

```
 <row>
    <column name='column1'>value1</column>
```

Is there a way to map or SET the column name so I can import using LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE?

Answer (score 2):

You've probably long since figured this out, but this answer from SO: [LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE with Inconsistent Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582837/load-xml-local-infile-with-inconsistent-column-names) should show you how if you have not.  I'm new to MySQL and working with a very similar problem to yours.  Hopefully this will help someone else if not you.