# How to load remote location xml file data to mysql/(any other) database

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, database, dbimport

I have found the solution to load xml file data to mysql db table [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582837/load-xml-local-infile-with-inconsistent-column-names)

My question is how I can load remote location xml file and dump it to mysql database table.

If you have any idea or have done something like this please help to find the solution.

Thank you

Comment: There are solutions for this everywhere.. Google it

Answer (score 0):

LOAD XML statement does not support retrieving files from a remote location. The file has to be either on the server, or on the client (LOCAL - if enabled in configuration). You need to write a script that saves the file either to the server or to the client from the remote location.

If you manage to map a remote shared directory to the local fileszstem, then you can import data that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I am doing the same as you have mentioned, save the file to the server and run it from there and It works, Just to avoid the download of the file and then run the script to insert to database. I was curious if I can give some remote location file path directly to LOAD XML function, It would have made process very easy.
Thanking you again for the clarification about the LOAD XML function, Now at-least  I will try for something else.